# Python selenium PhantomJS cant send keys

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, tor

Y try to log in Twitter using `Python3`, `Selenium` and `PhantomJS`. The login is work fine, but when you use tor on Twitter, Twitter have a second authentication form: in this case, the phone number associated with my account.
I can select the phone input tag but I can't use the method `send_keys()`.

This is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'
key = 'phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent'
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS[key] = userAgent

# use Tor
service = [
    '--proxy=127.0.0.1:' + '9050',
    '--proxy-type=socks5',]
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=service)

# Go to login
browser.get('https://twitter.com/login')
# Fill the login
fieldset = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('fieldset')
# Fill the username
input_username = fieldset.find_element_by_name('session[username_or_email]')
input_username.send_keys('your_user')
# Fill with the password
input_password = fieldset.find_element_by_name('session[password]')
input_password.send_keys('password')
# Summit
form = browser.find_element_by_class_name('js-signin')
button = form.find_element_by_tag_name('button')
button.click()

browser.save_screenshot('login.png')

# Find the phone input
phone = browser.find_element_by_id('challenge_response')
phone.send_keys('111222333')
```

And this is the error when try to `send_keys()`

```
WebDriverException: Message: TypeError - undefined is not a function (evaluating '_getTagName(currWindow).toLowerCase()')
```

Why I have this error? I can't to execute javascript code (I suppose it must be for the same reason as this).

I use `Python 3.5.2`, `Selenium 3.3.1` and `PhantomJS 2.1`

Comment: Does removing that line removes the error? Because this error seems to be with the driver of phantom